# Predicate logic universal quantifier and implication rule

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I have just started studying predicate logic and I don't perfectly know how to use the quantifiers yet in formulas, so I have this short question:

Does the following hold? $$\forall x(A \to B) \iff (\forall xA \to \forall xB)$$
So if I have the quantifier outside of the parentheses, can I apply it to every formula inside the parentheses?

I'm sorry if I have used some wrong terminology, I'm not used to talking about mathematics in english.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not consider some examples?

Comment: Are A, B predicates?  How does (if they do) each of A, B, relate to $x$?  Otherwise, without such information, your "biconditional" makes no sense.

Comment: yes A and B are predicate logic statements and there is no other information about x than it's just a variable.
I need this information to prove a logical consequence between two statements

Comment: Consider for example what happens if $A$ means "$x$ is odd" and $B$ means "$x$ is even". Then $\forall x A$ and $\forall x B$ are both true, so the implication on the right holds. But on the left ...

Comment: I see. Still having some hard time understanding this exactly. What I understand now is that for the left side the scope of the quantifier is the whole implication whereas on the right side it's the statements A and B each (if that makes sense). Well I have to show that $\forall x(A \to B) \implies \exists xA \to \exists xB$. So I tried to somehow open up the statement $\forall x(A \to B)$ to make it look bit more similar to the conclusion and then roughly say something like because $\forall xA \to \forall xB$ then $\exists xA \to \exists xB$ but this is obviously the wrong..

Comment: @HenningMakholm Did you mean "both false"?

Comment: @DerekElkins: Whoops yes.

Comment: So in the statement $\forall x(A \to B)$ the value of $x$ is same in $A$ and $B$ but in the statement $\forall xA \to \forall xB$ $x$ can have different values in A and B? Am I understanding this correctly?